# Uwp Select ComboboxItem when click on list

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, uwp, selecteditem

I have a form with a 2 items combobox in XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb_Category" PlaceholderText="Category" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="20,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="437" SelectionChanged="cb_Categoria_SelectionChanged">
<ComboBoxItem Content="Products"/>
<ComboBoxItem Content="Services"/>
</ComboBox>
```

I converted the combobox selected item to string so it can be added to my database and appear on my list.

```
    private void cb_Category_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cb_Category.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var combo = (ComboBox)sender;
            var item = (ComboBoxItem)combo.SelectedItem;
            content = item.Content.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Now what I want to do is when I select a item in my list, the combobox selects and show the same item. But I have no idea how?

[App Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF0F8.png)

As you can see when I click on a Grid Item I get all the values of the item in the textboxes except the combobox

Comment: ComboBox by default will show the item you selected from this list, please clarify if I am missing anything.

Comment: I'm using the same form to add/edit items in the database so when I click in an already created item on my list, all my textboxes fill with the information from the database but I can't get the combobox to do that.

Comment: Also would be better if you can share on how your list looks like.

Comment: @Dishant I just add an image

Comment: Please share the date structure(Class) of the item that is bind to that list if you can, if not, then I will help you with the solution with some default data type.

Comment: Can you help me with the default data pleas?

Comment: Please refer to my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the List item to your ComboBox you need to set the `ItemsSource` property as below:

```
cb_Category.ItemsSource = yourList;
```

**EDIT as per the updated Post**

Once your data is loaded you can do something like this on list `SelectionChanged`:

```
cb_Category.SelectedIndex = cb_Category.Items.IndexOf(myListView.SelectedItem);
```

If your List and ComboBox is not sharing the same data structure then you can do something like this:

Your List data structure:

```
Public Class MyList
{
  public int Property1 {get;set;}
  public int Property2 {get;set;}
  public string Property3 {get;set;} //Property mapped for ComboBox
  public int Property4 {get;set;}
}
```

Your ComoboBox DataStructure:

```
Public Class MyComboBox
{
  public int Property1 {get;set;}
  public string Property2 {get;set;} //Property that needs to be display in ComboBox
}
```

Than on list `SelectionChanged` first find the item in your `ComboBox` and then set it's `SelectedIndex'

```
var selectedItem = myComboBoxDataSource.where(x=>x.Property2.Equals(((MyList)myListView.SelectedItem).Property3));
cb_Category.SelectedIndex = cb_Category.Items.IndexOf(selectedItem);
```